# laravel polymorphic many to one

Tags: laravel, orm, one-to-many

i want to set relationship between this three entities

 CARGO - ITEM - ASSET

 each ITEM should be has one unique CARGO

 each ASSET should be has one unique CARGO

 each CARGO has many ITEM

 each CARGO has many ASSET
how can i design something like this in laravel?
in laravel one to many morph relation we have something like this:
COMMENT - POST - VIEDO

 each post has many comment

 each video has many comment

 each comment has one post/video 
i think laravel one to many morph can't resolve my problem

Answer (score 0):

**FK** in **ITEM** and **ASSET** which name is `cargo_id`

this is the densign you refer it

and in model you can use `belongsTo()` and `belongsToMany()`